# How to load PNG files with pygame.image?

Tags: python, image, pygame

I'm simply trying to load an image with pygame with that piece of code :

```
import pygame
myimage = pygame.image.load("bla.png")
```

And I get the error :

> pygame.error: File is not a Windows BMP file

Note that when I call `pygame.image.get_extended()` it returns 0.
How can I fix that and get the other formats ?

Thanks

Comment: in your example you are loading a gif?? but you want a png?

Comment: Well, he wanted to load a .PNG file, tried to load a .GIF file, and the Pygame system complained that it is not a .BMP file. I wonder where the .JPG file is, because that's probably the only thing that is missing here.

Comment: Oops, my bad. I actually tried to load 'bla.png' and the file in my directory is a png. Just corrected the example. The problem remains.

Comment: What platform are you on?  What version of pygame are you using?

Comment: I'm on Ubuntu 13.04 and I develop with python 3.3, I just installed pygame 1.9.2 following those instructions : http://python-forum.org/viewtopic.php?f=25&t=2716

Comment: You can always use PIL to convert images to bmp files.

Answer (score 3):

The [Pygame documentation for images](http://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/image.html) explicitly says

> > The image module is a required dependency of Pygame, but it only optionally supports any extended file formats.
> >     By default it can only load uncompressed BMP images.

So, I suppose you should run

```
pygame.image.get_extended() # returns a bool
```

to check if you can load images of other extensions. If not, I suppose you will need Python imaging libraries to be installed to get extended file formats to be supported by Pygame.

OR, you could always convert the images to BMP to avoid the hassle.

Comment: I've been trying to install imaging libraries, such as libpng or libjpeg, the error has changed. It's now : "Couldn't open 'bla.png'"

Comment: myimage = pygame.image.load("bla.png")
pygame.error: File is not a Windows BMP file.
By the way `pygame.image.get_extended()` still returns 0.

Comment: I suppose, you need some other imaging library, mostly PIL should do the job. Check out http://www.pythonware.com/products/pil/ & https://pypi.python.org/pypi/PIL‎